# Does commutators $[A, L(H)]$ in the center still imply the unbounded operator $A$ is in the center? If not, what could be a counterexample?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, lie-algebras

Let $A$ be an algebra over a field, $Z(A)$ the center of $A$.
An element $a\in A$ may or may not have the following property:
$$[a,A]\subseteq Z(A)\implies a\in Z(A).\qquad(\ast_A)$$
A well known example where every element satisfies $(\ast)$ is $B(H)$, the algebra of bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space $H$.
Here $[a,B(H)]\subseteq Z(B(H))$ implies $[a,b]$ is always a scalar thus $[a,b]=0$ (Problem 230, Halmos), i.e. $a\in Z(B(H))$.

I wonder if there is an unbounded operator NOT having $(\ast_{L(H)})$ where $L(H)$ is the algebra of linear operators on $H$.
I know there are non-zero scalar commutators, but it's still quite far from being a counterexample.

Comment: You are asking if there is an unbounded operator commuting with every bounded operator but the unbounded operator is not a scalar? The answer is no, let $x$ be in the domain of your operator and $\pi_x$ the projection onto $x$: Then $a\pi_x = \pi_xa$ implying that $x$ is an eigenvector of $a$. If every vector in the domain is an eigenvector then the operator is a scalar.

Comment: Reply to s.harp: No. The condition for the unbounded one is not that it is in the center of bounded operators, but every commutators it 'generates' is in the center (in L(H)'s case, is the scalar). Explicitly, the condition for the operator 'a' is '[a,b] is a scalar for every b in L(H)', and I want to know if such 'a' is in the center (i.e. a scalar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Let $A$ be unbounded and suppose $[A,a]=\lambda(a)1$ for any $a\in B(H)$ for which the commutator $[A,a]$ is defined, here $\lambda(a)\in \Bbb C$. If we let $p_x$ denote the orthogonal projection onto some $x$ in the domain of $A$ we have:

$$p_x A x-Ap_xx = \lambda(p_x) x \iff (1-p_x)Ax =  \lambda(p_x) x $$
but the left hand side is orthogonal to the right-hand side, so $\lambda(p_x)=0$. In particular you get
$$p_x A x = A x$$
and $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$. The only way  that every vector in the domain of an operator is an eigenvector is for the operator to be a scalar.